# Best way to write "nested if" for different ranges

Tags: python, if-statement

I am going to write down this pseudocode in python:

```
if (i < .1):
   doX()
elif (i < .3):
   doY()
elif (i < .5):
    doZ()
.
.
else:
    doW()
```

The range of numbers may be 20, and each float number which shapes the constraints is read from a list. For the above example (shorter version), it is the list:

```
[0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1]
```

Is there any pythonic way or a function which can do different functions for different associated ranges?

Comment: Change your pseudocode to a proper `if ... elif ... else` statement, and you pretty much have the right way to do it.

Comment: there is other ways to do it, but i will doubt it's pythonic. if those numbers are known ahead of time, then it's probably the right way of doing it already.

Comment: If you had a *lot* of boundary points, it would probably be worth building an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) that maps intervals to `doWhatever` functions, allowing O(lg n) lookups instead of O(n) lookups incurred by the `if` statement. I'm not sure just how many boundary points you would need to make the added complexity and overhead worthwhile.

Comment: @chapner It is exactly 20 boundaries. Is it possible to write your suggestion in a code for a very basic problem? I will extend it to mine.

Comment: `bintrees` should be sufficient to address your problem: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees you just need to look up using `ceiling_item(key)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from bisect import *
a=[0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1]
b=["a","b","c","d"]
print b[bisect_left(a,0.2)]
```

Comment: You could also do `b[bisect_left(a,0.2)]`.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin fixed

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that you should not use:

```
doX = lambda x: x + 1
doY = lambda x: x + 10
doZ = lambda x: x + 100
ranges    = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1]
functions = [doX, doY, doZ]
answer = lambda x: [func(x) for (low, high), func in zip(zip(ranges[:-1],ranges[1:]), function) if low <= x < high][0]
```

The point is, that getting to fancy with it becomes unreadable.  The if..elif..else is the *"one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."*.

Answer (score 1):

```
def a():
    print('a returned')

def b():
    print('b returned')

def c():
    print('c returned')

funcs = [a, b, c]

def sample_func(x, funcs=None):
    if x < 0:
        return None    
    thresholds = [.40, .60]

    for i, threshold in enumerate(thresholds):
        if x <= threshold:
            return funcs[i]()
    return funcs[len(thresholds)]()

sample_func(.1, funcs)
```

returns

```
a returned

sample_func(.65, funcs)
```

returns

```
c returned
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create the following dictionary with numbers as keys and functions as values:

```
d = {0.1:doX, 0.3:doY, 0.5:doZ, 1:doW}
```

Then use the following code:

```
for n,(k,f) in enumerate(sorted(d.items())):
    if (i < k) or (n == (len(d) - 1)):
        f()
        break
```

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter if the number of entries is small, but for a large number of entries Ohad's solution is much better.